# I can't see all the events for one day on the El Capitan calendar

Tags: calendar

In the Month view, the El Capitan calendar now includes the first week of the next month.  So the blocks for each day are smaller, and not all events can be shown.  Instead it says "3 more" or whatever.  But there is no way to see the additional events.  Clicking on the day opens a Create New Event default that can't be closed or deleted.  I need to see all my events/appointments when I open the calendar in the Month view. It also doesn't help that national holidays are listed twice.

Comment: Make the font smaller. Cmd -

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see all of your events (instead you see "2 more", etc., then the blocks are too small. Simply enlarge the calendar (by pulling on the right-hand bottom corner), and you will see all of your events.